# "Are we still on our meeting date" Does this phrase sound natural?

Tags: expressions, idioms

My friend and I have picked a day next week to hang out online on a video call -let's say it's Monday-. Sunday has come and I want to make sure we are having our online meeting as scheduled. What message can I send him?

can I say "Are we still on our meeting date"?
How is it said naturally in English speaking countries?

Comment: More likely "Are we still on _for_ our meeting?", or "Is our meeting still on?"

Comment: @psmears I would supply that as an answer, if I were you.

Comment: @psmears thank you.

Comment: Just ask, "Are we still on for next week?"